# Distributing the number of records in PostgreSQL cursors

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, postgresql-9.4

I have a stored procedure as below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION DELETE_REDUNDANT_RECORDS_STORED_PROCEDURE
RETURNS void AS
$func$
DECLARE
    interval_time            BIGINT DEFAULT 0;
    min_time                 BIGINT DEFAULT 0;
    max_time                 BIGINT DEFAULT 0;
    rec_old                  RECORD;
    rec_new                  RECORD;
    rec_start                RECORD;


    cursor_file CURSOR FOR
        SELECT distinct filename,systemuid FROM BOOKMARK.MONITORING_TESTING;

    cursor_data CURSOR FOR
        SELECT * FROM BOOKMARK.MONITORING_TESTING WHERE filename = v_filename AND systemuid=v_systemuid ORDER BY mindatetime, maxdatetime;

BEGIN
    -- Use cursors for iteration
    -- Business logic to delete and update the table records based on certain conditions
END;
$func$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The distinct query returns around a million records and is used for iteration on another cursor.

I want to distribute these million records into configurable chunks of data like for example 200k records each till all the records are read.
How can I achieve such functionality within my stored procedure?

Comment: Please don't use Indian words like 'lac' here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a window function call to the cursor's `SELECT` list:

```
(row_number() OVER ()) / 10000 AS chunk
```

That will add a number that you can use to split the result into chunks of 10000.

Comment: So my query would be like SELECT distinct filename,systemuid,(row_number() OVER ()) / 10000 AS chunk FROM BOOKMARK.MONITORING_TESTING; ? Will it create a chunk of size 10k each of the given distinct records?

Comment: It will add a number that is 0 for the first 9999 rows, 1 for the next 10000 rows, 2 for the next 10000 rows and so on. You can use this to split up the result. You didn't say how you plan to handle these chunks, so I don't know what more to tell you.

Comment: What I want to do with these chunks is use them one by one till the very end. For each chunk I will fetch the systemuid and filename and then use it on the other cursor so that performance is better